# Cross entropy: IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to train VGG16 to do classification. The model is copied from here:
https://medium.com/@tioluwaniaremu/vgg-16-a-simple-implementation-using-pytorch-7850be4d14a1

There are 22 classes in total. The sizes of my images are 1020*530*3 jpeg images in RGB format but they are resized to 224*224. So I guess the dimension should be fine. I don't know what causes the error. Any help is appreciated.

```
trainData = datasets.ImageFolder(
    root='myData',
    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224,224)), transforms.ToTensor()])
)
```

Here is the model.

```
class VGG16(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VGG16, self).__init__()
        self.conv1_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv1_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.conv2_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.conv3_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3_3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.conv4_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv4_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv4_3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.conv5_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv5_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv5_3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(25088, 4096)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4096, 4096)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(4096, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv1_2(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2_2(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv3_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3_2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3_3(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv4_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4_2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4_3(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv5_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv5_2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv5_3(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, 0.5) #dropout was included to combat overfitting
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, 0.5)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

But I get the following error message.

```
<ipython-input-2-e1599c555f7f> in train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    118         # Compute prediction error
    119         pred = model(X)[0]
--> 120         loss = loss_fn(pred, y)
    121 
    122         # Backpropagation

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
   1150         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1151                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
-> 1152                                label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)
   1153 
   1154 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   2844     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2845         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2846     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   2847 
   2848 

IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

Comment: Why are you select the first item of your batch with `model(X)[0]`?

Comment: i think that is the reason